# Checkbutton activo

Tags: python, tkinter

¿ hay alguna forma de que un `Checkbutton` aparezca ya activo por defecto?.
Pongo un trozo del código para que se vea como genero los interruptores:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk () 
root.title ("Grafic")
root.state('zoomed')
frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=1) 
frame1.config(bg='white') 
Checkbutton(frame1, text="canal 1 ",bg='red',  width=5,height=1, onvalue=1,relief='groove', bd=10,
            offvalue=0).pack()
Checkbutton(frame1, text="canal 2 ",bg='blue',  width=5,height=1,  onvalue=1,relief='groove', bd=10,
            offvalue=0).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puede establecer un estado de un control de casilla de verificación sin una variable booleana, usted debe usar una variable para cambiar el estado entre `True` o `False`, por tanto lógicamente usar una variable puede establecer el estado predeterminado del control.

**Por tanto quedaría así con base en su código:**

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
root = tkinter.Tk () 
root.title ("Grafic")
root.state('zoomed')
frame1=tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=1) 
frame1.config(bg='white')
VariableControl1 = tk.IntVar() # Variable 1
tk.Checkbutton(frame1, text="canal 1 ",bg='red',  width=5,height=1, variable=VariableControl1,relief='groove', bd=10).pack()
VariableControl1.set(1) # Activo por defecto variable 1

VariableControl2 = tk.IntVar() # Variable 2
tk.Checkbutton(frame1, text="canal 2 ",bg='blue',  width=5,height=1,relief='groove', bd=10,
            variable=VariableControl2).pack()
VariableControl2.set(0) # No activo por defecto variable 2
root.mainloop()
```

> La variable `IntVar()` establece verdadero o falso mendiante un valor entero, `BooleanVar()` es simlar solo acepta más que entre `True` o `False`.